# Migrate ASP.net Identity users to Firebase

Tags: mongodb, firebase-authentication, asp.net-identity

I am looking for a way to migrate ASP.net Identity users stored in MongoDB (using **AspNetCore.Identity.MongoDbCore v 1.0.8** NuGet package) to Firebase Authentication project.

In order to import users using Firebase CLI I need to specify the following parameters:

```
firebase auth:import ACCOUNT_FILE    \
    --hash-algo=HASH_ALGORITHM         \
    --hash-key=KEY                     \
    --salt-separator=SALT_SEPARATOR    \
    --rounds=ROUNDS                    \
    --hash-input-order=HASH_INPUT_ORDER
```

Where **hash-algo** = HMAC_SHA256; **rounds** = 10000; **hash-input-order** = SALT_FIRST;

Also, I need to provide the salt along with the password hash in the list of users (JSON file).

Please guide me how can I get the required parameters (**hash-key**, and **salt**) in order to successfully migrate the existing users to Firebase Authentication project.

Thanks!

I was able to create a new user in Firebase Authentication project using Firebase Admin API for .Net
and I was able to successfully authenticate the newly created user.

However I am unable to migrate any of the preexisting users that are currently stored in MongoDB.